# Http 500 Internal Server Error in Android

Tags: java, android

Android code

```
class BirthdayTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                System.out.println(uri[0]);
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                    System.out.println("responseString"+responseString);
                } else{
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //TODO Handle problems..
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            /* System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println(result);*/
        }

    }


 @RequestMapping(value="here is my url" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String Test(HttpServletRequest req) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Domain domain = (Domain)req.getSession().getAttribute("Domain");
            List<UserProfile> userProfiles = userProfileManager.getUpcomingBirthday(domain.getDomainId(),15);

            return gson.toJson(userProfiles);
        }
```

Webservice

This is the webservice I am calling from browser its working fine. But when I call from Android then I get a **500 internal server error**. But in server logs I see no error.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you debug it somehow on the server side? Or provide any info more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give an answer, but i think the session is null when you call the WS using Android. While if you call the WS using a browser the session could be mantained using cookie or sessionId i dont find any line of code that handles cookies or sessionId in some way.
IMO you shouldnt rely on session information.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever an [HTTP code](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) starts with a 5 (5xx), it means something got wrong on the server. It is not about your code here, on the android client side, but in the server side implementation.

> This is webservice I am calling from broweser its woriking fine ....But when I am calling from android then 500 internal server error

This may mean the the request payload that you are sending from your android app, must be different to that when you do it from your browser. Please print your request payload and double-check everything. Additionally, it might help you also give the request headers a look.

Comment: sometimes my request is work and sometimes did not work.why??

Comment: @Masum It is hard to tell without more details. Kindly share more details about your code

Comment: I post my method. you can see. And thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) instead of AsyncTask. It will solve the problem with a cookie.

Comment: I used retrofit. That's time create the problem. But when async task used. It's was fine.

Comment: I guess we need the request and the response via the postman.

Comment: when submitting with the postman, it's ok.but in the program it will be created this error.