# i want to upload images using multipart to backend using retrofit in android. i am getting 500 error whie it works in postman

Tags: java, android

**The Endpoint i use**

@Multipart
@POST("upload/{id}")
Call uploadmultipleIdentityImages(@Path("id") int customerId, @Part  MultipartBody.Part file1,
@Part MultipartBody.Part file2 );

**the method for uploading it..**

try {

**          f1 = new File(getPath(istImageuri)); **
f2 = new File(getPath(sndImageuri));

```
        RequestBody requestFile1 =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f1);

        RequestBody requestFile2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f2);

   
        //create multipartbody for ist image
        MultipartBody.Part body1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Work_id", f1.getName(),requestFile1);

        Log.e("docUploadfrag->", "Second Request Body");

        //create multipartbody for 2nd image
        MultipartBody.Part body2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("Bank_statement", f2.getName(),requestFile2);

        if (body1 != null && body2 != null) {

            Log.e("docUploadfrag ->", "Body 1& Body 2");

            Call<udRes> resCall = connectuser.uploadmultipleIdentityImages(getCusid, body1, body2);

            resCall.enqueue(new Callback<udRes>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<udRes> call, Response<udRes> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.e("docUploadfrag1", response.body().getStatus());

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There is an error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("docUploadfrag1", String.valueOf(response.code()) + " " + response.message());

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<udRes> call, Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please try again later ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("docUploadfrag11", t.getMessage());

                }
            });

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("docUploadfrager _>", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**The Error **
8022-8022/com.afarapartners.labalaba E/docUploadfrag1: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Please post what error do you get also on the question

Comment: @ashokpoudel done

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975282/http-500-internal-server-error-in-android)[Check this out]

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved. The Multipart body had the incorrect objects names supposed to sent to the server.